# rspec not reporting line number of error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For almost all my specs, when rspec reports an error, it informs me of the line number at the end of the path e.g.

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/eclubs_controller_spec.rb:21
```

However in one of my specs, it reports the error location like this

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/eclubs/members_controller_spec.rb[1:1:2:3:1]
```

which may make sense in terms of the nesting of blocks but frankly is rather cryptic.

The top part of the spec that works looks like this

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe EclubsController do
```

and the one that does not work looks like this

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe Eclubs::MembersController do
```

The only difference I can see in the two files is that one controller is namespaced, but I have other namespaced controllers that report the error line correctly.

What is causing this?

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell. Sometimes this happens when it's an included file that is causing the error... eg a syntax error in `rails_helper.rb` or the fixtures file. Not necessarily the actual problem here, but that can cause this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec uses the example id when the line number is not sufficiently unique to identify the example in question.

This can happen when examples are dynamically defined, for example in a loop:

```
(0..10).each do |i|
  it do
    expect(i).to_not eq(5)
  end
end
# rspec './my_spec.rb[1:6]'
```

Or when using a shared example group:

```
RSpec.shared_examples_for "not equal 5" do |i|
  it do
    expect(i).to_not eq(5)
  end
end

RSpec.describe do
  it_behaves_like "not equal 5", 5
  it_behaves_like "not equal 5", 4
end
# rspec './my_spec.rb[2:1:1]'
```

Comment: Spot on. In that file I have a shared example group.

Comment: ok, but is there a way to tell rspec NOT to do that? especially when it's not actually ambiguous (when you are using parameterized shared examples, but only 'calling' them once per context block, for example). I don't want to parse a tree in my head, I just want to click on the failing spec in iterm and fix the damn code.