# Output general line number when using loops in RSpec

Tags: rspec, metaprogramming, rspec-rails

## Question

Is it possible to get RSpec failures using example and nesting IDs of the form `rspec ./spec/whatever_spec.rb[1:3:1]` to show the line number it feels is ambiguous? Can it either be done in RSpec itself or using something similar to `__LINE__` when it's used in `class_eval '', __FILE__, __LINE__`?

### Background

#### or how to read `rspec ./spec/whatever_spec.rb[1:3:1]`

If you've ever seen the above output you may have found it hard to figure out which test was failing.

The reason according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884565/rspec-not-reporting-line-number-of-error/38888849#38888849) is

> "RSpec uses the example id when the line number is not sufficiently
>   unique to identify the example in question."

If we use a contrived example to illustrate the structure, the spec file would look something like

```
RSpec.describe do
  context 'first' do
    it "is not > 1" do
      expect(0).to_not be > 1
    end
  end

  context 'second' do
    it "is not > 1" do
      expect(1).to_not be > 1
    end
  end

  context 'third' do
    it "is not > 1" do # This is the test on line 15
      expect(2).to_not be > 1 # Our failing spec
    end
  end
end
```

This is an illustrative only to explain the structure. The output for this would actually be `rspec ./spec/whatever_spec.rb:15`. Our actual meta-programmed tests make it a little harder to see the structure since it uses loops. This error actually come from the following

```
RSpec.describe do
  %w(first second third).each_with_index do |nth, i|
    context "#{nth}" do
      it "is not > 1" do
        expect(i).to_not be > 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`[1:3:1]` can be read from right to left as "the **first** test in the **third** context block of the **first** class being described."

Comment: I really wish there was a way to override this too. It makes working with shared examples very annoying. I use the clickable links feature of iTerm to get to failures quickly, and this breaks that.